# Custom Layout can't add on activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried this [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker), but it seems the code only works for dialogs. I tried adding a layout into an activity but nothing displayed.
Is there anyway that I can draw a layout and set it for a view like in the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in his class `/src/com/fourmob/datetimepicker/date/DatePickerDialog.java` that he extends the `DialogFragment`. That's why it's always a dialog. But you can fork the project, modify that class to extend a regular Fragment or a regular Activity, then publish it back to Github and use it for your projects as well.